# Construct chains of pairs of numbers with one common member

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

I need to construct a chain of pair of numbers where:

1. In each pair, the first one is smaller than the second
2. In order to form a chain between two consecutive nodes, they must have one number in common. In other words, the link `(a,b) -- (c,d)` can be made if and only if either `a==c`, `b==c`, `a==d` or `b==d`
3. A pair cannot be made of the same number. In other words, if `(a,b)` exists, then `a!=b`

This may look like a *Longest increasing subsequence* but I actually want to chain consecutive pairs that have one **equal** member.

Example:

```
Initial list (unordered):
(0,1)
(2,3)
(1,6)
(4,6)
(8,9)
(2,8)
Result:
----- chain #1
(0,1)
(1,6)
(4,6)
----- chain #2
(2,3)
(2,8)
(8,9)
```

I could do an algorithm that will iterate over the entire list for each cell (O(n^2)), but I want to make it faster and I have the flexibility of ordering my initial array in any way I want (std::set, std::map, std::unordered_map, etc.). My list is made of tens of thousands of pairs so I need an efficient solution in terms of processing time.

Comment: i dont understand how "make a chain" connects to "longest subsequence". Are you looking for the longest chain for given elements?

Comment: Let your pair be `(x,y)`. Sort all pairs by `x` first, then by `y`. After that you can traverse through your pairs and determine which ones form a chain.

Comment: what are you trying to maximize/minimize?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: When I don't know how best to optimize something and research doesn't dig up any good leads (or when it does and I don't yet understand the problem well enough to realize I found a good lead) I go with the best algorithm my naïve understanding can come up with and start looking for patterns I can exploit. If that doesn't lead to something that meets the requirements, I'll go back to the research to see if I've learned enough to better deploy what I found or travel new research paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it in `O(N * log(N))` when you manage two lists, one sorted with respect to first the other sorted with respect to second.

The code has some duplication that I didnt bother to clean up yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <any>

struct pair_and_iter {
    int first;
    int second;
    std::any other_iter;
};

struct compare_first {
    bool operator()(int x,pair_and_iter p){ return x < p.first; }
    bool operator()(pair_and_iter p, int x){ return p.first < x; }
};
struct compare_second {
    bool operator()(int x,pair_and_iter p){ return x < p.second; }
    bool operator()(pair_and_iter p, int x){ return p.second < x; }
};
template <typename Iter,typename Comp>
Iter my_find(Iter first,Iter last,int x, Comp comp) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(first,last,x,comp);
    if (it != last && (!comp(x,*it) && !comp(*it,x))){
        return it;
    } else {
        return last;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::list<pair_and_iter> a {{0,1},{2,3},{1,6},{4,6},{8,9},{2,8}};
    std::list<pair_and_iter> b;

    for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it){
        b.push_back({it->first,it->second,it});
        it->other_iter = std::prev(b.end());
    }

    a.sort([](const auto& x,const auto& y){ 
        return std::tie(x.first,x.second) < std::tie(y.first,y.second); });
    b.sort([](const auto& x,const auto& y){ 
        return std::tie(x.second,x.first) < std::tie(y.second,y.first); });
    
    std::vector<std::vector<pair_and_iter>> result;
    std::vector<pair_and_iter> current_result;
    current_result.push_back(a.front());
    auto current = current_result.begin();
    b.erase(std::any_cast<std::list<pair_and_iter>::iterator>(current->other_iter));
    a.erase(a.begin());        

    while (a.size() && b.size()) {
        // look for an element with same first
        auto it = my_find(a.begin(),a.end(),current->first,compare_first{});
        if (it == a.end()) {
            // look for element where current->second == elem.first
            it = my_find(a.begin(),a.end(),current->second,compare_first{});
        }
        if (it != a.end()){
            current_result.push_back(*it);
            current = std::prev(current_result.end());
            b.erase(std::any_cast<std::list<pair_and_iter>::iterator>(it->other_iter));
            a.erase(it);
            continue;
        }

        // look for element with current->first == elem.second
        it = my_find(b.begin(),b.end(),current->first,compare_second{});
        if (it == b.end()) {
            // look for element with same second
            it = my_find(b.begin(),b.end(),current->second,compare_second{});
        }
        if (it != b.end()) {
            current_result.push_back(*it);            
            current = std::prev(current_result.end());
            a.erase(std::any_cast<std::list<pair_and_iter>::iterator>(it->other_iter));
            b.erase(it);
            continue;
        }        
        // no matching element found
        result.push_back(current_result);
        current_result.clear();
        current_result.push_back(a.front());
        current = current_result.begin();
        b.erase(std::any_cast<std::list<pair_and_iter>::iterator>(current->other_iter));
        a.erase(a.begin());
    }
    result.push_back(current_result);
    for (const auto& chain : result){
        for (const auto& elem : chain){
            std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/3xdYcbcTK):

```
0 1
1 6
4 6

2 3
2 8
8 9
```

I used `std::list` because it has stable iterators and constant time erase. `std::any` for type erasure because each list contains iterators to the other list. `a` is sorted with respect to `first` and `b` is sorted with respect to `second`. Hence `std::lower_bound` can be used to to find a match in `O(logN)`. A single linear search is traded against 2 binary searchs to find either `current->first` or `current->second` in a `first` of `a` and 2 binary searchs to find either `current->first` or `current->second` in a `second` of `b`. In total it is `O(N log(N))` for sorting plus `O( log(N) + log(N-1) + log(N-2) + .... log(1))` which equals `O(log( n! ))` if I am not mistaken.

PS: You didn't mention that you are looking for a longest chain, and this algorithm is not finding the longest chain. It just picks the first element of the remaining ones and uses the next element it finds to continue the chain.