# Declare a C++ std::list with elements that point to other elements in the list

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, graph, stl

I'm trying to use an std::list and an std::unordered_map to store a directed acyclic graph. Each list element stores a node key (unsigned) and its children. And the map stores, for each key, an iterator to the node in the list:

```
std::list<std::pair<unsigned, std::list<decltype(lst.begin())>>> lst;
std::unordered_map<unsigned, decltype(lst.begin())> nodemap;
```

But `decltype(lst.begin())` in the declaration of `lst` results in a compile error since `lst` is not defined yet. Can I define `lst` another way ?

Edit: using `std::vector<unsigned, std::list<unsigned>> vec` would probably work, where `list<unsigned>` contains indexes into `vec`. Not sure whether sticking with the initial `std::list` is better or worse.

Comment: I wrote an answer just recently where elements of two lists store iterators to each other. I used `std::any` https://stackoverflow.com/a/69412271/4117728, though there might be more convenient solutions

Comment: I assume in `std::list<decltype(lst.begin())` where you are trying to define `lst`?

Comment: @doctorlove yes, I just updated the question now to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write classes. Within the definition of the class, it is an incomplete type, which means you can use pointers (or references) to it.

The children pointers can be non-owning, with the map owning all the nodes.

```
class Graph {
    struct Node {
        unsigned key;
        std::vector<Node *> children;
    };

    std::unordered_map<unsigned, Node> nodes;
public:
    // graph behaviours
};
```

Comment: If the map is rehashed when adding a node to it, the Node.children pointers will be invalidated.

Comment: @patraulea iterators are invalidated by rehashing, but pointers are only invalidated by erasing that element